# Why does only the variable I put at the bottom get executed without console.log?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, console

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3];
const doubled = a.map((num) => {
  return num * 2;
});

const x = 2;

x;
doubled;
```

When I run the above program in console, only the variable at the bottom gets executed. So in the above code, I will only get doubled as the output ([2, 4, 6]) but there won't be any output from x. But if I have put x below doubled, then the output will be x (2) but nothing from doubled.

Why does this happen and what's going on behind the scenes here that I'm not getting?

(When I console.log both of them, then the behaviour is as expected and both get logged, but I'm curious about this odd behaviour without console.log)

Thanks!

EDIT: You can reproduce this by going to https://repl.it/languages/javascript and pasting the above code there.

Comment: I get `ReferenceError: a is not defined`. Please may you use a stack snippet to show what you mean? (See [mcve])

Comment: @evolutionxbox He formatted it incorrectly, the `a` declaration was not visible.

Comment: Are you pasting the entire thing into the console instead of typing them one line at a time? When you do that, the console only shows the value of the last expression that was pasted.

Comment: I would then assume it's because the console outputs the last expression value, which is the result of `doubled`. Try swapping the order of `x` and `doubled`. I would expect to see `2` in the console.

Comment: @Barmar and @ evolutionbox Is that how repl.it works as well? You can reproduce it by going to https://repl.it/languages/javascript and pasting the above code there.

Comment: Probably. This allows you to paste a large block of code without seeing all the intermediate values.

Comment: It has little to do with JavaScript and variables, and it's just about the way the console works interactively.

Comment: If you want control over what gets shown in the console, call `console.log()` explicitly.

Comment: @Barmar const a = [1, 2, 3];
const doubled = a.map((num) => {
  return num * 2;
});

const x = 2;

console.log(x);
console.log(doubled);

If I paste that in the console, both of the lines get executed. So the console only logs the last line by default unless I specifically tell it what to log?

Comment: Thanks for the help both of you!

Answer (score 1):

Executing code in the console (effectively?) uses `eval` to execute the code string entered into the console.

`eval()` returns the value of the last statement it evaluated, which the browser then writes to the console after any other output produced by the code during evaluation.

Hence the expected output from executing this code in the console:

```
>>console.log("hello")
```

is

```
hello
undefined
```

because the `console.log` method  returns `undefined`. For your examples, the value of `x` or `doubled` appears depending on which is the last expression statement in the code evaluated by `eval`.

What can be confusing is that `eval` returns `undefined` for statements that are not *expression statements*:

```
 "let x = [1,2,3]"
```

returns `undefined` when evaluate as a string because it has no value, but

```
 let x;   x = [1,2,3];
```

returns `[1,2,3]` when evaluated because `x=[1,2,3];` is an expression statement.